# With pandas in python, why can't i use a variable for a altering multiple dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

precursor code, same for both:

```
import pandas as pd

train = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
holdout = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

def process_age(df):
    df["Age"] = df["Age"].fillna(-0.5)
    cut_points = [-1,0,5,12,18,35,60,100]
    label_names = ["Missing","Infant","Child","Teenager","Young Adult","Adult","Senior"]
    df["Age_categories"] = pd.cut(df["Age"],cut_points,labels=label_names)
    return df

def create_dummies(df,column_name):
    dummies = pd.get_dummies(df[column_name],prefix=column_name)
    df = pd.concat([df,dummies],axis=1)
    return df

train = process_age(train)
holdout = process_age(holdout)
for x in ["Age_categories", "Pclass", "Sex"]:
    train = create_dummies(train, x)
    holdout = create_dummies(holdout, x)
```

"correct" code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale
# The holdout set has a missing value in the Fare column which
# we'll fill with the mean.
holdout["Fare"] = holdout["Fare"].fillna(train["Fare"].mean())

columns = ["SibSp","Parch","Fare"]

train['Embarked'] = train['Embarked'].fillna('S')
train = create_dummies(train,'Embarked')
holdout['Embarked'] = holdout['Embarked'].fillna('S')
holdout = create_dummies(holdout,'Embarked')
for y in columns:
    train[y + '_scaled']= minmax_scale(train[y])
    holdout[y + '_scaled']= minmax_scale(holdout[y])
```

What I want to do is:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale
# The holdout set has a missing value in the Fare column which
# we'll fill with the mean.
holdout["Fare"] = holdout["Fare"].fillna(train["Fare"].mean())

columns = ["SibSp","Parch","Fare"]

for x in [train, holdout]:
    x['Embarked'] = x['Embarked'].fillna('S')
    x = create_dummies(x,'Embarked')
    for y in columns:
        x[y + '_scaled']= minmax_scale(x[y])
        x[y + '_scaled']= minmax_scale(x[y])
```

doing the code I want to use, does not assign to the dataframes I am trying to modify. I've tried this sort of thing in the past and it didn't work then, so I am left to assume that you can't use a variable in place of the dataframe name.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, keep in mind that if you want to access and modify elements in a `list` using a `for`, you must assign this list to a variable, otherwise you won't be able to access your modified elements later on. So, first you need something like this:

```
my_dataframes = [train, holdout]
```

Next, when running `for` loops, Python creates copies of your iterable items. For example, if you run

```
my_words = ['hello', 'my', 'friend']
for word in my_words:
    word=word.upper()
    print('Modification:', word)
print(my_words)
```

Your output will be:

```
Modification: HELLO
Modification: MY
Modification: FRIEND
['hello', 'my', 'friend']
```

This happens no matter what your list items are,, from strings to DataFrames. If you want to really modify the items of your list, you must either access their index or create a new list appending the modified items to it.

**Accessing your items index**

```
my_dataframes = [train, holdout]
for i, df in enumerate(my_dataframes):
    df['Embarked'] = df['Embarked'].fillna('S')
    df = create_dummies(df,'Embarked')
    for y in columns:
        df[y + '_scaled']= minmax_scale(df[y])
        df[y + '_scaled']= minmax_scale(df[y])
    my_dataframes[i] = df
```

Running this code will give you your desired DataFrames inside the original list `my_dataframes`.

**Creating a new list**

```
my_dataframes = [train, holdout]
modified_dataframes = []

for df in my_dataframes:
    df['Embarked'] = df['Embarked'].fillna('S')
    df = create_dummies(df,'Embarked')
    for y in columns:
        df[y + '_scaled']= minmax_scale(df[y])
        df[y + '_scaled']= minmax_scale(df[y])
    modified_dataframes.append(df)
```

In this case you'll keep the original DataFrames in `my_dataframes` and get the new ones in `modified_dataframes`.

Hope this was useful to you. Let us know if you have further questions.